# how to print words that only contain letters from a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to find all words from a text file(that I have turned into a list in python)that are made up of letters contained within a randomised string of vowels and consonants

Comment: Could you please show what you have already tried? If you need a start, you can think of `for` looping through each list, and using `in` for each word.

Comment: Split the string into a list of words, then iterate the words and check which ones contain the letters in your random string.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```py
[w for w in words if set(w) == set(random_str)]
```